# How can I detect when a NSPersistentStore needs to be saved?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have an iOS application where I use coreData to store my "documents". They all share a common NSManagedObjectContext, and I frequently save the context.

I would like to keep track of the last modification date for the various "documents" (where each one is a separate NSPersistentStore) and store the date on a particular unique "root" object that each store has.

I could try to keep the modification time stamp up to date while the document is being modified, but it would be cleaner and more robust if I could just find out which persistent stores need saving at the time I am saving the context.

I can't find any way to detect if a persistent store needs saving. I can query the NSManagedObjectContext to see which managed objects need saving, although I can't find an easy way to see which store an object belongs to.

It seems like this is not such a strange thing to do and core data has all of the information that I am looking for, but I am having trouble finding an easy way to get access to that data.

Does anyone know of an easy way?

If I can't find an easier way, I will simply loop over the deleted / modified / inserted objects from the context, and write special code for each entity type to determine the store that the object belongs to.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[managedObject objectID] persistentStore]` is the persistent store you're looking for (or possibly nil if the object has not been saved yet).

The documentation suggests that it's nil if you've assigned it to a store but haven't saved; I'm not sure that this is true (and I don't see anywhere else where this info might be saved). I'd check it behaviour on 3.x, 4.x, and 5.0 beta if you have access to it.